# Structure of non abelian finite p-groups

Tags: finite-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product, p-groups, wreath-product

I am familiar with the concepts of direct products, semi-direct products, wreath products and central products of groups. After seeing the classification of finite $p$-groups upto order $p^4$,(Theory of Groups of Finite Order; W.Burnside), I have observed that most of these groups are in the form involving the products mentioned above. My question is the if we can write any non abelian finite p-group in some form of the products mentioned above ? And if not ? Kindly provide me with a suitable counterexample .

Comment: "Can we write any non-abelian finite p-group in some form of the products mentioned above?" What groups are you allowed to start with?

Comment: Group of order $p^n$.

Comment: No I'm asking what "basic" $p$-groups are you allowing when trying to construct an arbitrary $p$-group using direct products, wreath products, and so on? Do you want to use only abelian $p$-groups? Only cyclic groups? I can write any group $G$ trivially as a direct product: $G\times \{0\}$, which clearly you don't want. So what counts as "nontrivial" for you?

Comment: @halrankard Any non abelian p-group. ( not in the trivial manner which you have written)